# Websphere database issue

Tags: java, websphere

I am trying to use oracle as a datasource in a websphere application without using JNDI. I have the connection string configured in my app but on server startup I see:
"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.137.1.247:1521:ORCL"
I think this is a classpath issue. I have the ojdbc6.jar file in my application's lib directory and I've tried multiple ways to add that to websphere's classpath. I am using websphere 8.5. Any thoughts on how I should resolve this issue? (or any further information you need)

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you show us the code that initiates the database connection and describe the structure of your application (ear,war, modules etc.)

Comment: And why not use JNDI?

Comment: Have you registered your Oracle driver using `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`?

Comment: All, I sincerely apologize for horrible description of the problem. I could use jndi, the reason I didn't think I could was because I couldn't find anything about how to set a default schema for the connection in websphere. So perhaps I should describe it like this. I have an app that has a query ("SELECT * FROM my_table"). The problem is that the application is saying "table doesn't exist" even though it does and I can query it with the same user defined in the datasource configuration. How do I make it so the connection can use the correct schema as default?

Comment: If you are using a JDBC 4.1 compliant driver then you can use `connection.setSchema(String schema)` on the connection.  Otherwise it can be done using SQL with `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = your_schema_name_here`.  Note you'll need to do either of those each time you obtain a connection from the datasource.  Otherwise you can do it in the actual schema call like `SELECT * FROM your_schema_name_here.my_table`.

Comment: There's also another a way to configure WebSphere to set the schema.  If you enable connection validation (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/udat_jdbcdatasorprops.html) and use "Validation by SQL Query", that query will be executed by WebSphere before returning the connection.  So you would just use `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = your_schema_name_here` as your SQL string.